# Aligning dynamic images with GD

Tags: php, image, alignment, gd

I have an app where people can upload a photo and it gets embedded onto another image which they can download. Like adding a photo to a greeting card. It can be seen at design.some.cards

The upload is first placed in a resizable, draggable div so users can position it where they want and at the size they want.

Everything is working however when they change the position of the image in the div the final image has the black embedded image container in the right position and size but the photo isn't lining up with the black container.

I've added top and left offsets for the black container and photo so people can line it up manually but would rather they didn't need to do this step. They should just be able to position the photo in the div and that's how it looks in the final image.

Oddly, when the users use the offsets and line the photo up with black container it looks right but if they then move the photo in the div that's when the black container lines up correctly but the photo doesn't.

Here is some of the code - the parameters are being captured with js then posted.

```
$theimage = '/path/'.$theimage; // background image
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($theimage);

$photo =  "/path/uploads/".$_POST["photo"];
$jpg_photo = imagecreatefromjpeg($photo);
$rezphoto= "/path/uploads/resized-".$_POST["photo"];
$jpg_photo1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($rezphoto);

// resizing and moving the div sends coords to a form
$phototop =  $_POST["phototop"];
$photoleft =  $_POST["photoleft"];

// phBlLeftOffset & phBlTopOffset - users input to align the black if not lining up
// phLeftOffset & $phTopOffset - users input to align the photo within the black 

//The dynamic resizing isn't posting accurate coords, realigning here
$photoPozLeft = $photoleft+63;
$photoPozTop = $phototop-26;
$photoPozLeftBlack = $photoleft+$phBlLeftOffset+360;
$photoPozTopBlack = $phototop+$phBlTopOffset+185;

imagecopy($jpg_image, $jpg_photo1, $photoPozLeftBlack, $photoPozTopBlack, $photoPozLeft+$phLeftOffset, $photoPozTop+$phTopOffset,$photowidth, $photoheight);
```

Ideally I'd like

```
imagecopy($jpg_image, $jpg_photo1, $photoPozLeftBlack, $photoPozTopBlack, $photoPozLeft, $photoPozTop,$photowidth, $photoheight);
```